# Sequence queue - converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the next sequence queue: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}}$. Does the queue converges or diverge?

---

***My attempt:***
I have tried to show that $\frac{1}{n^2}>|\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}|$ for any $n>0$, and then by the comparation test we get that since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$ converges, we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}|}$ converges too, and by a theorem we have that since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{|\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}|}$ $\implies$ $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}}$ converges. Is that right?

Comment: Yeah, a direct comparison test works for this. You were right to compare the following: $$\frac{1}{n^2}>\left|\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}\right|$$ Now because the $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$$ converges by the p-test, you can conclude that the original series also converges.

Comment: @ObsessiveInteger So my attempt is right? but can you show me how I satisfy that $\frac{1}{n^2}>|\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}|$. for $\frac{1}{n^2}>\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}$ it's easy since we get by algebra that $n^3+1>0$ for $n>0$. However, for the negative it's not that easy.

Comment: You could make an argument by saying that the numerator of $\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}$ grows smaller faster compared to that of $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and similarly, the denominator of $\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}$ grows bigger much faster compared to that of $\frac{1}{n^2}$. This means that $\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}$ is reaching $0$ faster compared to $\frac{1}{n^2}$, hence, the inequality is true. Of course you can see that graphically as well. Plug in both functions into desmos and you will see.

Comment: @ObsessiveInteger seeing that throw desmos is good, but can I actually verify that by using just inequality algebra? and thank you for the answer.

Comment: Why don't you do the limit comparison test instead? That way you do not have to worry about proving the inequality.

Comment: @ObsessiveInteger because the expression can be negative. I wanted to look at bigger values of $n$, when the whole expression is positive, but I saw that we cannot use the comparison test when we don't have all values to satisfy such that the expression is positive. So I appeal to ||

Comment: Technically when we take the limit in the limit comparison test, we take the absolute value of $\left |\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right |$, so by definition we are forcing it to be a positive number.

Comment: @ObsessiveInteger yes. I have forced it in my attempt, but it is totally unnecessary by your way. But both of them are right and are nearly the same. Right?

Comment: Yeah both ways are right. Technically, when you are using the direct comparison test, you do not have to prove that $a_n>b_n$, as long its true, you can use the direct comparison test. So yeah, both methods work just as good, but I feel that the limit comparison test is more intuitive since you get to see the algebra working out..

Comment: @ObsessiveInteger I see. Note that I wrote you one last question, that I had to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are trying to prove that the series, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}}$$
converges.

Let us use the Limit Comparison Test. That is, if $a_n>0$ and $b_n>0$, then if $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L$$ for some real number $L$. Then, if $b_n$ converges, by the limit comparison test, $a_n$ must also converge.

Let $a_n=\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}$ and we say $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$. Then, $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\\
\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{(n^2-n-1)(n^2)}{n^4+n^2+1}\right)\\
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n^4-n^3-n^2}{n^4+n^2+1}\cdot \frac{\frac{1}{n^4}}{\frac{1}{n^4}}\\
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{{1-\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{n^2}}{1+\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^4}}\right)\\
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1-0-0}{1+0+0}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$

Hence, we have shown that the $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=L$ converges because it equals some constant; in this case, $1$.

Now, because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges by the p-test, (since $p=2>1$), we can conclude that the series, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}}$$ must also converge by the limit comparison test.

Comment: Ohhh I didn't try using this, in this way. Thank you!

Comment: One last thing, by limit comparison test we have to show that the sequence queue $\frac{n^2−n−1}{n^4+n^2+1}$ is positive. How do we show that? or you saying we disregard the first negative elements of the sum?'

Comment: Technically you do not have to show that, note that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ starts at $n=1$, so we are only considering values for $n$ that are positive. Notice that for values greater than $1$, $\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}$ can never be negative.

Comment: So you are saying that becuase the only negative fraction of the sum is $-\frac{1}{3}$ then there exist elements that if we sum them we get a positive number bigger then $\frac{1}{3}$?

Comment: That sounds about right.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I continue from where you stopped,

Easy to show that :

$$\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1} < \frac{n^2-1}{n^4+1} < \frac{n^2}{n^4} < \frac{1}{n^2} $$

When we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^2}}$ converges.

Therefore, by comparison test :

$$\underset{converges}{\underbrace{\frac{n^2-n-1}{n^4+n^2+1}}} < \underset{converges}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{n^2}}}$$

Comment: However, what stops us from doing so for just the expression without ||, is that when $n$ has small values then the whole expression is negative, and then you cannot use the comparison test, so we have to show it with ||.

Comment: @aasc232 By the limit test we get the equation aims to zero  so can see that only the first element in the sum has negative value do not forget is the sum of this equation .

Comment: Can you remind me the limit test?

Comment: And the comparison test is when you have $0\le a_k\le b_k$ for all $k>0$, with the first elements of $a_k$ included, then if $b_k$ converges we get that $a_k$ converges too. So since we have that $a_k$ isn't positive for all $k>0$ we cannot use it. That is what I tried telling you. Isn't right?

Comment: @aasc232 Do the $n=1$ term separately $$|\frac{1^2-1-1}{1^{4}+1^2+1}|<\frac{1}{1}$$ and then ATB's answer applies for all $n>1$ as $\frac{n^{2}-n-1}{n^{4}+n^{2}+1}$ is positive for $n>1$. Of course, a finite number of terms does not determine the convergence and can be disregarded in general when checking convergence